# Esvaziar campo ao fornecer dado inválido

Tags: php

Essa é a primeira vez que tenho contato com PHP, e queria saber como eu poderia fazer com que o sistema reconhece um login inválido e ao invés de redirecionar o usuário para a página inicial (como está acontecendo), esvaziar o campo preenchido e exibir uma mensagem alertando que o login está incorreto.

PHP (o código é maior, mas coloquei a parte que julgo importante):

```
if (isset ($_POST ['enviar'])){// se o campo enter for clicado

       $username=$_POST['username'];
       $senha=$_POST['senha'];

       $query = @mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE username='$username' AND senha ='$senha'"); // Verifique no banco se o login e a senha digitados existem.
       $conta = @mysql_num_rows ($query);// conte os dados do banco selecionados na variável query

       if ($conta == '0') {// se o valor digitado não existir 

            echo "<script language= 'javascript'> window.alert('Os campos  não correspondem');</script>"; 

            header ("LOCATION: ../index.php");


        }else{

            while ($resultado= @mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
```

FORMULÁRIO:

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="php/usuarioautenticado.php">

            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required="required" placeholder="Usuário"/>

            <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" required="required" placeholder="Senha"/>

            <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />

        </form>
```

Comment: Só com essas informações não é possível te ajudar. Inclua o formulário.

Comment: Irei editar a postagem

Comment: Altere o `Location: ../index.php` para direcionar para a página que desejar e pesquise sobre *flash messages* para ver como pode fazer para exibir a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma e utilizar AJAX para pegar o resultado da verificação em PHP
Exemplo:

```
$(function($) {
    // Quando enviado o formulário
    $('#frmLogin').submit(function() {

        // Limpando mensagem de erro
        $('div.mensagem-erro').html('');

        // Mostrando loader
        $('div.loader').show();

        // Enviando informações do formulário via AJAX
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(resposta) {

            // Se não retornado nenhum erro
            if (!resposta)
                // Redirecionando para o painel
                window.location.href = 'painel.php';
            else
            {
                // Escondendo loader
                $('div.loader').hide();

                // Exibimos a mensagem de erro
                $('div.mensagem-erro').html(resposta);
            }

        });

        // Retornando false para que o formulário não envie as informações da forma convencional
        return false;

    });
});
```

Verifique nestes endereços exemplos com mais detalhes:
http://www.agenciamagistri.com.br/post/108/
http://clubedosgeeks.com.br/programacao/php/sistema-de-login-php-jquery-mysql